# Minidlna server only appearing after restart

Tags: networking, dlna, minidlna

I've got minidlna running, and it seems to be working perfectly, with one catch. The television can't see it when searching for servers.

After starting the television and unsuccessfully searching, I can restart the minidlna service, and search again with the TV - that second time, the TV instantly finds the server. From that point on, everything works perfectly.

Just speculating, I believe that the TV sends a signal requesting servers when it's searching - presumably that isn't working properly?

... and when starting the service, minidlna sends out a signal broadcasting it's location? So presumably if the TV is already on and listening, it sees that signal triggered by minidlna, which is why it knows about the server when I search a second time?

The TV is on the wireless network, and the server is on the LAN.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I have same issue with minidlna 1.1.4

Answer (score 5):

The `notify_interval` option in `/etc/minidlna.conf` should be changed to a lower value as the default is 900 seconds, so that every 15 minutes minidlna sends a multicast advertisement.

That is too long time to wait for the TV to start seeing your files, so I set a 30 seconds interval instead:

```
sudo nano /etc/minidlna.conf
notify_interval=30
```